# Convert multiple columns into a column of map on Spark Dataframe using Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have a dataframe having variable number of columns like Col1, Col2, Col3.
I need combine Col1 and Col2 into one column of data type map by using the code below.

```
val df_converted = df.withColumn("ConvertedCols", map(lit("Col1"), col("Col1"), lit("Col2"), col("Col2")))
```

But how can I do it for all columns when I don't know the number and names of the columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to expand the column list of the DataFrame via `flatMap` into a `Seq(lit(c1), col(c1), lit(c2), col(c2), ...)` and apply Spark's [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@map(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  ("e", "f", "g", "h")
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

val kvCols = df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c), col(c)))

df.withColumn("ConvertedCols", map(kvCols: _*)).show(false)
// +---+---+---+---+---------------------------------------+
// |c1 |c2 |c3 |c4 |ConvertedCols                          |
// +---+---+---+---+---------------------------------------+
// |a  |b  |c  |d  |Map(c1 -> a, c2 -> b, c3 -> c, c4 -> d)|
// |e  |f  |g  |h  |Map(c1 -> e, c2 -> f, c3 -> g, c4 -> h)|
// +---+---+---+---+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! We get a new DF by flatmap(). Is there any performance concern if we deal with big data here?

Comment: @Chi CHEN, generating a simplistic MapType column like this isn't more computationally expensive than many other general transformations, though Space-wise it does require decent memory/storage to accommodate the generated data which consists of all column values along with duplicated column names (as keys).

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `from_json` and `to_json` to get a map type column:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "ConvertedCols", 
    from_json(to_json(struct("*")), lit("map<string,string>"))
)

df2.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+------------------------------------+
|c1 |c2 |c3 |c4 |ConvertedCols                       |
+---+---+---+---+------------------------------------+
|a  |b  |c  |d  |[c1 -> a, c2 -> b, c3 -> c, c4 -> d]|
|e  |f  |g  |h  |[c1 -> e, c2 -> f, c3 -> g, c4 -> h]|
+---+---+---+---+------------------------------------+
```